# Python: json_normalize gives AttributeError for list of dict values

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where 2 columns are nested column having decimal value: `df.tail(1).to_dict('list')` gives this kind of data

```
 {'nested_col1': [array([{'key1': 'CO', 'key2': Decimal('8.940000000')}],
  dtype=object)], 'nested_col2': [array([{'key3': 'CO', 'key4': 'P14', 'key5': Decimal('8.940000000'), 'key6': None}],
  dtype=object)]}
```

I am trying to explode the dataframe with this:

```
df = (df.drop(cols, axis=1)
        .join(pd.concat(
            [pd.json_normalize(df[x].explode(), errors='ignore').applymap(
                lambda x: str(x) if isinstance(x, (int, float)) else x).add_prefix(f'{x}.') for x in
             cols],
            axis=1)))
```

With this I am getting below error in some cases:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_load.py.py", line 365, in <module>
    df = prepare_data(data, transaction_id, cohort_no)
  File "data_load.py.py", line 274, in prepare_data
    df = flatten_dataframe(cols_to_explode, df)
  File "data_load.py.py", line 204, in flatten_dataframe
    df1 = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(df[c].explode()) for c in cols],
  File "data_load.py.py", line 204, in <listcomp>
    df1 = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(df[c].explode()) for c in cols],
  File "/project1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py", line 270, in _json_normalize
    if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
  File "/project1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py", line 270, in <genexpr>
    if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'values'
failed to run commands: exit status 1
```

anything still I am missing here or any better way to do the same?

Expected Output should be:

```
nested_col1.key1,nested_col1.key2 nested_col2.key3 ... like this
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my input data exactly look like this, list of dict and I want to explode the column

Comment: print(df["some_col_name"].iloc[0:1]) gives what I provided in question. In my output I should have some_col_name.key1 and some_col_name.key2 as new column along with other columns

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input? `df.head().to_dict('list')`

Comment: @mozway added in the question

Comment: Can you also provide the matching expected output?

Comment: @mozway added expected output

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is only one element for each nested column:

```
out = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(df[x][0]).add_prefix(f'{x}.') 
                     for x in cols], axis=1)
out = out.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(out)
print(out)

# Output
  nested_col1.key1  nested_col1.key2 nested_col2.key3 nested_col2.key4  nested_col2.key5 nested_col2.key6
0               CO              8.94               CO              P14              8.94             None
```

Note: you can replace `[0]` by `.explode()` if you have more than one record in each nested list.

Comment: I must not use nested_col1 in the code, . I have input say nested_cols=['nested_col1','nested_col2'] and use this in a loop probably

Comment: Sorry bad copy/paste. I fixed it. Can you check it please?

Comment: still it gives error

Comment: What's wrong? The first line or the second?

Comment: json_normalize line.  `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: Do you have nan values instead of a list of 1 element?

Comment: yes, that is true. example: {'nested_col1': [array([], dtype=object)], 'nested_col2': [array([], dtype=object)]}

Comment: @Dcook. The exception is `NotImplementedError`?

Comment: stacktrace given in the question

Comment: Nan values are not the problem. I tried my code (and your) with a row with `nan` value and does not raise exception. Can you identify which row(s) is the problem?

Comment: I am thinking how can I identify that particulat row from large dataset. what is the best way to find that?

Comment: As I can't reproduce your error, it's difficult to give you answer. However, you can slice your rows. Try `df.iloc[0:10][x][0]` instead of `df[x][0]` until it raises an error.

Comment: got the file which is raising this error, ran it locally with out any issues. is there any chance because of python version?

Comment: Python version, I don't think so but check version of Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
cols = ['nested_col1', 'nested_col2']

out = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(df[c].explode()) for c in cols],
                keys=cols, axis=1)
out.columns = out.columns.map('.'.join)
```

Output:

```
  nested_col1.key1 nested_col1.key2 nested_col2.key3 nested_col2.key4 nested_col2.key5 nested_col2.key6
0               CO      8.940000000               CO              P14      8.940000000             None
```

Comment: not sure why in my larger dataset it gives that error which I mentioned

Comment: @Dcook maybe you have invalid json/dictionaries? NaNs likely

Comment: yes, NaNs is there and I dont want to drop the Nan because that will remove rows

Comment: You should drop them then reindex or join back to original

Comment: can. you please add that in the solution as well? because if I drop then it will remove entire rows isn't it!

Comment: Can you provide such an example for clarity?

Comment: let's say for this sample row `{'nested_col1': [array([],
  dtype=object)], 'nested_col2': [array([{'key3': 'CO', 'key4': 'P14', 'key5': Decimal('8.940000000'), 'key6': None}],
  dtype=object)]}`, do mean to say I need to remove this entire row?